# Nodejs file deflate does not produce expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, zlib, fs

I receive a byte array over the network containing a compressed xml file. I use the following methods for inflating and deflating.

```js
let file = "./xmls/test.xml";
let arr = [120, 218, 188, 189, 121, 115, 219, 72, 150, 47, 250, 255, 251, 20, 169, 154, 59, 225, 174, 30]; 
//only took the first 20 bytes of this huge array for this example

zlib.inflate(Buffer.from(arr), (error, resultBuffer) => {
    fs.writeFile(file, resultBuffer, () => {
        console.log('done');
    })
});
```

The result xml file is 280.458 bytes without any non-ascii (illegal) characters.
After this is done i call the following code in a new process

```js
let file = "./xmls/test.xml";
fs.readFile(file, (readFileError, readFileBuffer) => {
    zlib.deflate(readFileBuffer, (deflateError, deflateBuffer) => {
        console.log(deflateBuffer);
        // <Buffer 78 9c bc bd 69 73 db 48 96 36 fa fd fe 8a 54 cd 9d 70 77 bf ...
        // 120 156 188 189 105 115 219 72 150 54 250 253 254 138 84 205 157 112 119 191
    })
})
```

As you can see the initial byte array doesn't match the deflated output
    `120 218 188 189 121 115 219 72 150 47 250 255 251 20 169 154 59 225 174 30` vs
    `120 156 188 189 105 115 219 72 150 54 250 253 254 138 84 205 157 112 119 191`

I have tried a stream based approach as well but it produced the same results.
How can I get the initial byte array after deflating the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you can't, but it *doesn't matter*. In general you should not expect that you can decompress and then recompress to exactly the same thing, unless you are using the same library, the exact same version of the library, and the same compression settings. Who knows where that compressed data came from, and what was used to generate it.

The only guarantee is that if you compress and then decompress that you get exactly what you started with. That is what is meant by lossless, and that is what you should be verifying. There is no need to reconstruct the same compressed data streams, since in general *many* compressed data streams can produce the same uncompressed output. It is up to the compressor to find a good one, based on the algorithms and specific code used, and the balance between execution time and compression ratio requested by the user.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for the detailed answer! My code execution was failing and I thought it was because of this, but it turned out there was a bug somewhere else. So a big thanks for the TIL!